# why the data types in my visual studio showing in white color while in other system showing in blue color?

Tags: angular, typescript

Details of the program

[image]

(I am just a beginner learning visual studio)

I just tried to enter all the data types by creating a new component in typescript while comparing with my friends its showing different in colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the theming to manipulate the colors as you wish:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score 0):

Because your friends will most likely have selected another Theme.

You can change this by: `File > Preferences > Color Theme`